# Sheets IF Function setup and/or formatting errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Cell C5 on the Trip Assignment Form tab is a dropdown selection list of destinations.  I am trying to make sheets automatically fill in the C6 cell with the matching address (coming from a tab called Schools).  When I put the below formula in I get an error or FALSE but I cannot figure out why.

=if(C5=Schools!A1, C6=Schools!B1, "Other Error")

I need to make the formula work for any destination selected so that the appropriate address is inserted into the cell.  Can I do this like the way I am thinking or would Apps Script be better and if so how would I go about that?

["Trip Assignment Form"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQWDl.jpg)
[image]

["Schools" data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tQSZ.jpg)

[image]

Link to copy of my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xkwxjtf6syEd-zGaPUVsyE2_6Kfczu8c-8W3RuRg9CY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you'll provide an image of your spreadsheet I'd be glad to assist you.  I apologize but I don't like to follow links off of this site

Comment: @Cooper - I just added two photos, please let me know if you need more.

Comment: I don't use formulas very much but I'm pretty sure that this is an easy use of `vlookup`.  So you can take a look at it but some other volunteer will come around some time today and teach us both something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible to do with Google Apps Script but it's probably not the easiest way to go**

You can use the onEdit trigger and this sort of code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet12' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==1 & e.value!='') {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet12');
    var v1=sh1.getRange(1,1).getValue();
    var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet13');
    var v2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<v2.length;i++) {
      if(v2[i][0]==v1) {
        sh1.getRange(2,1).setValue(v2[i][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Your setup:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='assignment sheet name' && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart==5 & e.value!='') {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('assignment sheet name');//assignment sheet name
    var v1=sh1.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getValue();
    var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('schools sheet name');//schools sheet name
    var v2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<v2.length;i++) {
      if(v2[i][0]==v1) {
        sh1.getRange(6,3).setValue(v2[i][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I’ll take a look at your script. It might be a bit beyond my skill level but I suspect I should be able to make it work. I believe onEdit will be good as well.

Comment: Yeah. I suspect people that like formulas would use `=VLOOKUP()` and they would probably already know how to use it.  I don't because I don't like using them.  To me, it just enables people who can't program to make a huge mess that no one can decipher.  But that's just my opinion based upon my experience.

Comment: Can anyone comment on the use of vlookup() on this project?

Comment: when I ran the example you gave me I am getting an error of range is not defined on the second line of the code below:

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();

Comment: That's because you probably ran it from the script editor.  This function requires an event object.  It is intended to run off of an onedit trigger which only occurs on user edits.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It works perfectly and I believe my last question is how do I properly align the cells, for instance, C5 and C6, in the code?  I have tried a few things and cannot get it to work.

Comment: I configure the bottom  for you.  I'm not what the exact sheet names are so you will have to fill them in but I think the rows and cols are correct based upon the images.

Comment: I've got it all figured out, thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(C5, Schools!A:B, 2, 0)
```

- Lookup C5 in Schools A:B and retrieve the second column